# How do I jump to tags instead of lines?

Tags: tags, plugin-vimwiki

I'm using vim as note-taking software.   My notes grow to thousands of lines across 7 different files.

If I was writing code, I would be able to jump to a function definition in a different file with a vim plugin.   Or if I open a list of compile errors or grep matches in vim, I could jump to a line in a different file with just two keypresses.

My problem is that I want to jump to one note file from another.   This will probably involve tagging the location i wish to jump to.

Hopefully you know what I'm asking now.  I can't type in a reference to a second file, (other than using the exact line number file:999 ), but I still need a way to type in references in the files, since I want to organize the same tasks across different note-files.

How can I do this?  Would writing in markdown help?

https://superuser.com/questions/290082/how-can-i-configure-custom-vim-tags-for-my-text-file-notes offers a solution by binding a key to vimgrep

Answer (score 5):

There are probably better ways but you could the help functionality as long as the filetype being help is ok. I basically use it to write down things I'm learning as I keep learning how to use gvim, it's only been 20 years :).

At the moment I have one file that I edit elsewhere then copy to where the help file is as an archive. It's hit 1600 lines so I'll start breaking it up into separate files, ie a index and section by section.

At the bottom or top of each document you need something like
`vim:tw=88:ts=4:sw=4:ft=help:norl:foldmethod=indent:foldclose=all:modifiable:noreadonly:conceallevel=3`

The important bits

- `vim` - Thanks to @D. Benknoble it sets the file up to load vim related flags, poor summary :(
- `tw=88` - Sets the text width. I use a big screen
- `ts=4` - Sets tab spaces to 4
- `ft=help` - **Important** Sets the filetype to text
- `noreadonly` - Probably dangerous as it allows edits
- `foldmethod=indent` - I use indenting to separate the top level headings and the detail heading, dunno the vim word for headings :)

Then you define a help topic as follows

`|sf-search-flags|` - `|` sets the tag and allows jumping between tags using `CTRL-]`

And the sub topics as so

`*sf-search-flags*` - Where `CTRL-]` takes you. You can go to the previous tag using `CTRL-o`

It looks like this

[image: Help Topic]

`Ctrl-]` on `sf-search-flags` takes you to

[image: The note]

The colours are syntax formatting I'm playing with to make things stand out with out bold etc

After you save the file you need to use

`:helptags {dir}` (`dir`) is Optional if you are in the directory) to build the help file tags

**See**

`h :help`

`h :helptags`

`:help modeline`

**Update:** Fixed an error and added a better screenshot

Comment: `vim:` see `:help modeline`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks that helps

Answer (score 3):

I think with vim-wiki you can set anchors (from the help):

```
Anchors~

A wikilink, interwiki link or diary link can be followed by a '#' and the name
of an anchor.  When opening a link, the cursor jumps to the anchor. >
  [[Todo List#Tomorrow|Tasks for tomorrow]]

To jump inside the current wiki file you can omit the file: >
  [[#Tomorrow]]

See |vimwiki-anchors| for how to set an anchor.
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I'm playing around with (for my own minimalist wiki setup) is the following (assume all notes are in `~/notes`):

- `setlocal path+=$HOME/notes/**` for any files in `~/notes` (this can be done with autocommands or with ftplugins by adding `note.` to the filetype of any file in `~/notes`, though the latter is slightly more complicated)
- use `gf` to jump between files: no special syntax required, just type the name of a file and `gf` it (like a cross link)
- if you use `gF` instead, you can have references with line numbers (not quite like tags, though)
- use `:find` and its variants to interactively find a file to jump to
- use `:vimgrep /.../ ~/notes/**` to search